# javascript loop through an element in an object

Tags: javascript

I feel guilty asking this, but alas i'm having trouble pulling out and listing a specific element within an array of objects and was wondering if somebody had a better idea of how to loop through and find these.

The objects I have are called groups, and in the groups the elements I need listed are called passcode_field.

Because what I need is nested within the actual object, I know I can't just have them displayed. I've always had a weakness in coding with loops.

Here's what i've tried.

```
for (passcode_field in groups) {
  groups.passcode_field
}
```

This is not getting me what I need. Would anybody be able to take a crack at what I need with this one here?

Comment: try this `groups[passcode_field]`

Comment: for an array of objects called `arr` try `arr.map(obj => obj.passcode_field)`. If `passcode_field` is a variable, use the bracket notation suggested by Uma Kanth.

Comment: passcode_field inside a  'for (passcode_field in groups)' should be any string. You are not obligate to declare it as obj inside groups

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function is handing for picking things from arrays:

```
let result= groups.map((group) => {
    return group.passcode_field;
}
```

`result` will be an array containing the `passcode_field` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(passcode_field in groups){
     for(m in passcode_field)
    {
      use m to access the list
   }
}
```

or use console.log(groups) and find out how to access them.